# Stock options' exercise price not specified

Tags: compensation

I was offered stock options at the start-up I work for, but the agreement does not specify the exercise price:

"The exercise price of the Options shall be equal to the fair market value of the underlying Common Stock as of the date of grant, as shall be determined by the Parent Board in its sole discretion."

Is that normal? Or should I ask for it to be specified?

Comment: You may certainly ask what the price was on the date of grant, that is, your "strike price."  Ask your supervisor, who may refer you to an executive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you’re reviewing isn’t the option itself - but a promise to give you options.

When you receive each option, the exercise price will be assigned. It will be the estimated market price of the stock (probably from the last valuation that happened during a financing round).

What you describe is the norm.